# Error response from daemon: No such container

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I am new to docker, I am using Alibaba Cloud ECS Instance and just following the [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockerimages/) but while trying these steps I got an error:

```
xxx@ubuntu:~$ docker run -t -i training/qbots /bin/bash
root@0de606236049:/# gem install json
Fetching: json-1.8.3.gem (100%)
Building native extensions. This could take a while…
Successfully installed json-1.8.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for json-1.8.3…
Installing RDoc documentation for json-1.8.3…
root@0gf805966049:/# exit
exit
xxx@ubuntu:~$ docker commit -m “add json gem” -a “xxx” \ 0gf805966049 ouruser/qbots:v2
Error response from daemon: No such container: 0de606236049
xxx@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 3):

Listing containers by running `docker ps -aq` can include containers that have been removed. Attempting to perform an operation on a container that was included in the output of `docker ps -aq`, for example `docker rm -f`, results in the error Error response from daemon: No such container.

Workaround: Run `docker rm -f` again.

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, you just need to omit `\` in the command you are executing,

Instead of this

> docker commit -m “add json gem” -a “xxx” \ 0gf805966049
>   ouruser/qbots:v2

try the below:

> docker commit -m “add json gem” -a “xxx” 0gf805966049 ouruser/qbots:v2

Let me know if that helped, Thanks